# combining two attributes under the same column in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have following ER:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Which results in following tables:

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

I try to combine them in following way:
room_id | room_name

What I tried is the following.

```
SELECT room_id, b.bedroom_name, k.kitchen_Name
from   bedroom b full outer join kitchen k using (room_id)
;
```

Which give me:
room_id | bedroom_name | kitchenName

Giving b.bedroom_name and k.kitchenName the same alias results in the same structure:

```
 SELECT room_id, b.bedroom_name as room_name, k.kitchen_Name as room_name
    from   bedroom b full outer join kitchen k using (room_id)
    ;
```

room_id | room_name | room_name_1

Is there a way to get the structure I mentioned above with:

room_id | room_name

where bedroom_name and kitchen_name are listed unter room_name ?
Is it possible to group it? Like first kitchens, or first bedrooms?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXZur.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uSm3.png

Comment: Ok, So what is the question?

Comment: @Popeye I added something to the chapter, I hope its clearer now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is `UNION` you need, I'd say.

```
select 'R' what, room_id, bedroom_name room_name
from bedroom
union all
select 'K' what, room_id, kitchen_name room_name
from kitchen
--
order by what, room_name;
```

Comment: With this I also get an "implicit grouping" or? Like it displays first the bedrooms then the kitchens

Comment: It is not determined, because there's no ORDER BY clause. If you want to sort data by certain criteria, include it. I don't know which one you'd want to get.

Comment: How could I force the order first kitchens, then bedrooms or vice versa? I updated the question

Comment: Include additional column which shows "what is what" (I called it exactly like that - `what`). Then sort by that column. If you don't want to see that value, then use query I posted (edited, by adding the WHAT column) as a **subquery** and fetch only values you're interested in.